# iframe not showing content

Tags: html, iframe

I want to show a page, for example:google. That's what I'm using iframe for.  But the iframe content is not shown.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCv4c.png)

```
<iframe name=miframeflotante src="https://google.com" width=400 height=550 frameborder="0" scrolling=yes marginwidth=2 marginheight=4 align=left></iframe>
```

Comment: Lots of site (including Google) set the [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header to `sameorigin`. This tells the browser that if page on a different domain (e.g. `example.com`) tries to use the page in an iFrame, the browser should block it

Answer (score -1):

This is because `X-Frame-Options` doesn't set. You can do it on the server only, by set the response headers to `X-Frame-Options = SAMEORIGIN` or load iframe source from the same domain.

Comment: Your answer reads as if OP is trying to **stop** the iframe from displaying. It's the opposite... they want to know why the iframe **isn't** showing the page from `google.com`

Comment: It's impossible now to load some web sites via IFrame due to security reason.